# Fragment not visible inside layout but works correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've already read many questions about the same problem, but none of the answers had fixed my problem.

This is the layout of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:host="clyky.cartracker.activities.RegistrationActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_default_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_default_right_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_id_card"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_bottom_margin"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_bottom_margin"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/txtConfirmPassword"
        android:hint="Confirm password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_bottom_margin"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_bottom_margin"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/txtSurname"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_bottom_margin"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Registrati"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/registrationContainer">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment is added inside the last `FrameLayout` `registrationContainer`:

```
LoadingRegistrationFragment f = LoadingRegistrationFragment.newInstance(args);
Utilities.addFragment(R.id.registrationContainer, f, null, getSupportFragmentManager());
```

This is my `addFragment` method:

```
public static void addFragment(int containerID, Fragment toAdd, @Nullable String tag, FragmentManager manager)
    {
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.add(containerID, toAdd, tag);
        trans.commit();
    }
```

And this is my `LoadingRegistrationFragment`'s `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        username = args.get("username").toString();
        encryptedPassword = args.get("password").toString();
        name = args.get("name").toString();
        surname = args.get("surname").toString();
        listener = (RegistrationListener) getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(com.devspark.progressfragment.R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
        sendRequest();

        return v;
    }
```

My fragment works correctly, it's just invisible and I can't figure out why.
I've checked with the debugger if `v` in my `onCreateView` is `null` but no, it has got a value.
I've also tried to wrap my activity layout in a `ScrollView` to see if the fragment appears too below, but it was still invisible.

Comment: for debugging purpose, just hide all objects and place only framelayout to test whether fragment is loaded. add weight to framelayout. If possible can you update with pic, how the screen is loaded.

Comment: Please go ahead and share your fragment XML

Comment: @RedM it's an external library, I don't have the fragment XML, but it's just a circular indeterminate progress bar. this is the library: https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Comment: @RedM Anyway, I don't think it's a problem of this XML, because I use this fragment many times in my app, and this is the only point where it's invisible

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `trans.replace(containerID, toAdd)` instead of `trans.add(containerID, toAdd, tag)`

And change attributes to your fragment

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/registrationContainer">
```

Comment: @Clyky try to change FrameLayout attributes as I add in answer

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity container, instead of having this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/registrationContainer">
</FrameLayout>
```

Replace it with this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/registrationContainer"/>
```